# How to update google play services on the emulator android studio

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services, updates

Please help me, I am a beginner in android
When running my  android application about geolocalisation the emulator shows me "app-name will not run unless you update google play services" I tried to install the packages but no difference the problem persists.